# why auto variable won't become reference when I use std::string::operator[]?

Tags: c++, string, reference, operator-keyword, auto

The std::string::operator[] should return char reference:

```
 char& operator[] (size_t pos);
```

But when I'm passing it to an auto type, it will become a simple char. Why won't it become a char& ?

I have the following code:

```
std::string str = "Hello";
auto strRef = str[1];

strRef = std::toupper(strRef);
std::cout  << "str after:" << str << std::endl;
```

On the output I will get "Hello" instead of "HEllo".

Comment: Try `auto& strRef` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define the variable as non-reference and non-pointer, the reference part of the initializer will be ignored then `strRef` is deduced as `char`; the rule is same as [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction).

You need to declare it as reference explicitly.

```
auto& strRef = str[1];
```